# Custom class comparison needed for binary_search()

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm, binary-operators

I have a custom class and `std::vector` filled with objects of this class. And I want to do `binary_search` in this array.

I've overloaded operators on my class like this:

```
bool operator ==(const someClass&);
bool operator > (const someClass&);
bool operator < (const someClass&);
```

and they are working fine (they have bodies, yep).

Now I have an error Error

```
2   error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const someClass' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Should I make copy constructor (already overloaded =, but it didn't helped) or add something else to operators?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the operator const:

```
bool operator < (const someClass&) const;
```

without that, only the RHS is const.